# Reverse-engineering asm using sub / cmp / setbe back to C? My attempt is compiling to branches

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

this is the assembly code i am supposed to translate:
f1:

```
subl    $97, %edi
xorl    %eax, %eax
cmpb    $25, %dil
setbe   %al
ret
```

heres the c code I wrote that I think is equivalent.

```
int f1(int y){

  int x = y-97;
  int i = 0;

  if(x<=25){
    x = i;
  }
  return x;
}
```

and heres what I get from compiling the C code.

_f1:                                    ## @f1

```
.cfi_startproc
```

### %bb.0:

```
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset %rbp, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
                  ## kill: def %edi killed %edi def %rdi
leal    -97(%rdi), %ecx
xorl    %eax, %eax
cmpl    $123, %edi
cmovgel %ecx, %eax
popq    %rbp
retq
.cfi_endproc
```

I was wondering if this was correct / what should be different and if anyone could help explain how jmps work as I am also trying to translate this assembly code and have gotten stuck
f2:

```
cmpl    $1, %edi
jle .L6
movl    $2, %edx
movl    $1, %eax
jmp .L5
```

.L8:

```
movl    %ecx, %edx
```

.L5:

```
imull   %edx, %eax
leal    1(%rdx), %ecx
cmpl    %eax, %edi
jg  .L8
```

.L4:

```
cmpl    %edi, %eax
sete    %al
movzbl  %al, %eax
ret
```

.L6:

```
movl    $1, %eax
jmp .L4
```

Comment: Note that `cmpb` is unsigned comparison. Also, the asm version returns 0 or 1, your C version doesn't.

Comment: One possibility is: `int f1(int y){

  unsigned char x = y-97;

  return (x <= 25);
}` .To see the assembly generated you can try it on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1TrOcr)

Comment: Thanks that site looks super useful for testing thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack exchange is not a reverse engineering service nor an optimization service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc8.3 -O3 emits exactly the asm in the question for this way of writing the range check using the unsigned-compare trick.

```
int is_ascii_lowercase_v2(int y){
    unsigned char x = y-'a';
    return x <= (unsigned)('z'-'a');
}
```

Narrowing to 8-bit *after* the `int` subtract matches the asm more exactly, but it's not necessary for correctness or even to convince compilers to use a 32-bit `sub`.  For `unsigned char y`, the upper bytes of RDI are allowed to hold arbitrary garbage (x86-64 System V calling convention), but carry only propagates from low to high with sub and add.

The low 8 bits of the result (which is all the `cmp` reads) would be the same with `sub $'a', %dil` or `sub $'a', %edi`.

**Writing it as a normal range-check also gets gcc to emit identical code, because compilers know how optimize range-checks**.  (And gcc chooses to use 32-bit operand-size for the `sub`, unlike clang which uses 8-bit.)

```
int is_ascii_lowercase_v3(char y){
    return (y>='a' && y<='z');
}
```

**[On the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'//+good+with+clang+(which+assumes+the+input+is+zero-extended+to+32-bit)%0Aint+is_ascii_lowercase(unsigned+char+y)%7B%0A++++return+(y-(unsigned)!'a!')+%3C%3D+(unsigned)(!'z!'-!'a!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+good+with+gcc%0Aint+is_ascii_lowercase_v2(int+y)%7B%0A++++unsigned+char+x+%3D+y-!'a!'%3B%0A++++return+x+%3C%3D+(unsigned)(!'z!'-!'a!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+is_ascii_lowercase_v3(char+y)%7B%0A++++return+(y%3E%3D!'a!'+%26%26+y%3C%3D!'z!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+is_ascii_lowercase_branchy(char+y)%7B%0A++++unsigned+char+x+%3D+y-!'a!'%3B%0A++++if+(x+%3C+25U)+%7B+%0A++++++++return+1%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:38.58047761453351,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g83,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:30.92561720616293,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O1+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:30.49390517930357,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**, this and `_v2` compile as follows:

```
## gcc8.3 -O3
is_ascii_lowercase_v3:    # and _v2 is identical
    subl    $97, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpb    $25, %dil
    setbe   %al
    ret
```

---

**Returning a compare result as an integer, instead of using an `if`, much more naturally matches the asm**.

But even writing it "branchlessly" in C won't match the asm unless you enable optimization.  The default code-gen from gcc/clang is `-O0`: anti-optimize for consistent debugging, storing/reloading everything to memory between statements.  (And function args on function entry.)  **You need optimization, because -O0 code-gen is (intentionally) mostly braindead**, and nasty looking.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

```
## gcc8.3 -O0
is_ascii_lowercase_v2:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    subl    $97, %eax
    movb    %al, -1(%rbp)
    cmpb    $25, -1(%rbp)
    setbe   %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

---

gcc and clang with optimization enabled will do if-conversion to branchless code when it's efficient.  e.g.

```
int is_ascii_lowercase_branchy(char y){
    unsigned char x = y-'a';
    if (x < 25U) { 
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

still compiles to the same asm with GCC8.3 -O3

```
is_ascii_lowercase_branchy:
    subl    $97, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpb    $25, %dil
    setbe   %al
    ret
```

---

**We can tell that the optimization level was at least `gcc -O2`**.  At `-O1`, gcc uses the less efficient setbe / movzx instead of xor-zeroing EAX ahead of `setbe`

```
is_ascii_lowercase_v2:
    subl    $97, %edi
    cmpb    $25, %dil
    setbe   %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    ret
```

I could never get clang to reproduce exactly the same sequence of instructions.  It likes to use `add $-97, %edi`, and cmp with `$26` / `setb`.

Or it will do really interesting (but sub-optimal) things like this:

```
# clang7.0 -O3
is_ascii_lowercase_v2:
    addl    $159, %edi    # 256-97 = 8-bit version of -97
    andl    $254, %edi    # 0xFE; I haven't figured out why it's clearing the low bit as well as the high bits
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    $26, %edi
    setb    %al
    retq
```

So this is something involving `-(x-97)`, maybe using the 2's complement identity in there somewhere (`-x = ~x + 1`).

Answer (score 4):

Here is an annotated version of the assembly:

```
# %edi is the first argument, we denote x
subl $97, %edi
# x -= 97

# %eax is the return value, we denote y
xorl %eax, %eax
# y = 0

# %dil is the least significant byte (lsb) of x
cmpb $25, %dil

# %al is lsb(y) which is already zeroed
setbe %al
# if lsb(x) <= 25 then lsb(y) = 1
# setbe is unsigned version, setle would be signed

ret
# return y
```

So a verbose C equivalent is:

```
int f(int x) {
  int y = 0;
  x -= 97;
  x &= 0xFF; // x = lsb(x) using 0xFF as a bitmask
  y = (unsigned)x <= 25; // Section 6.5.8 of C standard: comparisons yield 0 or 1
  return y;
}
```

We can shorten it by realizing y is unnecessary:

```
int f(int x) {
  x -= 97;
  x &= 0xFF;
  return (unsigned)x <= 25;
}
```

The assembly of this is an exact match on Godbolt Compiler Explorer (x86-64 gcc8.2 -O2): https://godbolt.org/z/fQ0LVR

Comment: `(unsigned)x <= 25U;` is still a 32-bit comparison.  If you want to more exactly describe the asm using C, you should cast to `unsigned char` instead of letting the optimizer do that to implement `&= 0xFF`.  Of course, C doesn't actually have narrow operations; `unsigned char < unsigned char` promotes both sides to `int` (with zero-extension to preserve the value), according to the default integer promotions.