# How do i check whether characters are within certain ascii value ranges?

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii, masm, range-checking

How do i check whether a character is between 0-9, A-Z, and a-z? I understand that you can use cmp char, 'A' or cmp char, '0', etc. However if i have to check three different ranges, how do i do that?

If i need to check whether 'A'<= C <= 'Z', then i would have to check whether the character value is below A first, and then whether it's less than or equal to Z. But since 0-9 are below A, how do i account for that without messing up logic? The same goes for Z, since a-z are above Z. Posting with my logic I have so far. I feel so dumb for not getting simple stuff, but i'm a beginner and I've been working on this for several days and now I'm having to start over again, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
_asm
{
   mov ecx, 127
   mov esi, 0
   mov ebx,LocalBuffer[esi] ;LocalBuffer is a c++ array 

Loop1:
   cmp ebx, 'a'     ;ebx is the 0'th index value of LocalBuffer
   jb notLowercase  ;If character value is below 'a'
   cmp ebx,'z'
   jbe CharCount    ;if it's less than or equal to 'z' 
   cmp ebx,'A'
   jb notUpperCase ;If less than 'A', but then won't this discard 0-9?
   cmp ebx,'Z'
   jb CharCount    ;If it's less than 'Z', but what about greater than Z?
   cmp ebx,'0'
   jb NotDigit     ;If less than '0'
   cmp ebx,'9'
   jb CharCount    ;What if it's greater than 9?


notLowerCase:  
;DO I LOOP BACK TO LOOP1, MOVE ON TO THE NEXT CHARACTER OR SOMETHING ELSE? 

notUpperCase:
;SAME ISSUE AS NotLowerCase

notDigit:
;SAME ISSUE AS LAST 2

CharCount:
;Do something
```

Comment: Read about [std::isdigit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), [std::isalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) and [std::isalnum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum).

Comment: @PeteBecker this is for assembly language not c++

Comment: Then don't tag it C++.  [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](//stackoverflow.com/a/54585515) explains how to check for an alphabetic character in 4 instructions.  If this is the same histogram problem you were working on before, you *don't* need to filter while reading, just make your array of counts have 256 elements (for every possible `uint8_t` value) and then only loop over the ones you want to print.

Comment: Your problem is `mov ebx,LocalBuffer[esi]`.  That loads 4 bytes.  You want `movzx ebx, byte ptr LocalBuffer[esi]` to load one.  [this answer shows how](//stackoverflow.com/q/22621340).

Comment: how do you do it in any other language?

Comment: @PeterCordes, you've been very helpful these past couple days, thank you.  So i can just use an `OR` on the ebx with 20h? So for example if ebx was 'A', I did the calculations and it turns into 61h which is 'a'. I basically understand how it works, but can you explain possibly in simple simple terms what's going on when you `OR ebx, 20h`?

Comment: Have a look at [How to access a char array and change lower case letters to upper case, and vice versa](//stackoverflow.com/a/35936844) which has a well-commented use-case.  `OR` with 20h forces upper-case characters to lower-case, and doesn't make any non-alphabetic characters into lowercase, so you can do that on a copy of your register.  Make sure you don't destroy your only copy because you still need to *count* upper separately from lower; you're just creating a temporary to branch on.

Comment: @PeterCordes okay thanks! One last thing. If i want to access the actual index itself of an array to increment the index value by one, how do i got about doing that since i can't use something like `mov array[index],value`? 

Say i put the value of the character into a dl register and then move that index value of an array into al, and increment it. How do i move that incremented value back INTO the array index?

Comment: Zero-extend your index into a pointer-width register like EAX.  Exactly the same way you need to for loading from the count array in the first place.  Just don't destroy that index register while loading / incrementing.

Comment: I'm not sure i entirely follow. So i do something like this   `movzx eax, byte ptr array[index]`, then increment al?

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach is to order the ranges in an ascending (or descending) way. Then you can use the `cmp`s in an ON/OFF style:

```
   mov ecx, 127    ; Check a 127 char string
   mov esi, 0
Loop1:
   movzx ebx, byte ptr LocalBuffer[esi]   ; Load a byte from the address  
   cmp bl, '0'     ; '0' = 48 - all lower values mask are NOT IN THE SET
   jb  notInSet    ; 
   cmp bl,'9'      ; '9' = 57 - all lower are IN THE SET
   jbe CharCount   ; It is a number 
   cmp bl,'A'      ; 'A' = 65 - all lower are NOT IN THE SET
   jb  notInSet    ; If less than 'A'
   cmp bl,'Z'      ; 'Z' = 90 - all lower are IN THE SET
   jbe CharCount   ; It is an uppercase char
   cmp bl,'a'      ; 'a' = 97 - all lower are NOT IN THE SET
   jb  NotInSet    ; 
   cmp bl,'z'      ; 'z' = 122 - all lower are IN THE SET
   jbe CharCount   ; It is a lowercase letter
   ; FALL THROUGH for greater values
notInSet:  
   inc esi
   loop Loop1
   jmp Final

CharCount:
   ; DO SOMETHING (that doesn't mess up ECX, ESI)
   inc esi
   loop Loop1
   ; FALL THROUGH to Final

Final:
   ; END of this snippet
```

As you can see, the values that are checked do ascend. For example, a value of `3` (=51) will first check if it is below 48 (=NO), then check if it is below 57 (=YES), so the second jump is taken.

---

An alternative is using a jump table with indexed addressing. In this approach you define the ranges as a table of boolean values (0=NotInSet, 1=CharCount):

The table should be set up like this in the `.data` segment for your scenario (note the alternating values of `0` and `1`, the ON/OFF style mentioned above):

```
.data
  JumpTable db 48 dup(0), 10 dup(1), 7 dup(0), 26 dup(1), 7 dup(0), 26 dup(1), 133 dup(0)
```

Then the code could look like this:

```
   mov ecx, 127
   mov esi, 0
Loop1:
   movzx ebx, byte ptr LocalBuffer[esi]   ; Load a byte from the address  
   movzx eax, byte ptr JumpTable[ebx]     ; Retrieve the ebx'th value of the table[
   test eax, eax    ; Check if it's zero
   jnz  CharCount   ; If it's not, it's a char, so jump to CharCount 
   ; FALL THROUGH TO notInSet
notInSet:  
   inc esi
   loop Loop1
   jmp Final

CharCount:
   ; DO SOMETHING (that doesn't mess up ECX, ESI)
   inc esi
   loop Loop1
   ; FALL THROUGH to Final

Final:
   ; END of this snippet
```

The table has 256 values, the full ASCII range, either 0 or 1.

In both cases you can move the `inc esi` to the beginning, right after the value has been read by `movzx ebx, byte ptr LocalBuffer[esi]`.

Comment: Okay thanks @zx485, i'll look into this and figure out how to implement it into my program

Comment: Remember what happens when the `loop` instruction in `notInSet` falls through; you should probably put a `jmp` in there.  Seems the OP got mixed up by that and asked [Why is my code only printing out the first value 127 times?](//stackoverflow.com/q/58795363)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I fixed this and also moved the `movzx ebx, byte ptr LocalBuffer[esi]` to be part of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't debug your branching until you fix [How to load a single byte from address in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20727379) - you're loading 4 bytes of characters and comparing that whole 32-bit value against `'a'` and so on.  Use [`movzx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx) instead of `mov ebx, LocalBuffer[esi]` because it's a `char` array.

If you've been single-stepping your code in the debugger, maybe you've noticed that all 4 bytes of `ebx` are non-zero.  That's why your cmp/branches aren't working or doing what you expect.

---

@zx485 explained the general case of a chain of branches to go through until you can definitely accept or reject an input.

But you can also simplify by using efficient range-checks using the unsigned-compare trick.  e.g. [Reverse-engineering asm using sub / cmp / setbe back to C? My attempt is compiling to branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974851/reverse-engineering-asm-using-sub-cmp-setbe-back-to-c-my-attempt-is-compili/54976091#54976091) shows how that works for *just* the lower-case ASCII range.

Even better, ASCII is conveniently designed so the A-Z and a-z ranges align with each other, and don't cross a `%32` boundary, so you can force a byte to lower-case with `c |= 0x20`, or to upper case with `c ^= ~0x20`.  Then you only have that one range to check for alphabetic characters.

`OR` with 20h forces upper-case characters to lower-case, and doesn't make any non-alphabetic characters into lowercase, so you can do that on a copy of your register.

See [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536362/what-is-the-idea-behind-32-that-converts-lowercase-letters-to-upper-and-vice/54585515#54585515) and especially [How to access a char array and change lower case letters to upper case, and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932273/how-to-access-a-char-array-and-change-lower-case-letters-to-upper-case-and-vice/35936844#35936844) for MSVC inline asm that loops over a char array and checks for alphabetic or not.

Make sure you don't destroy your only copy because you still need to *count* upper separately from lower; you're just creating a temporary to branch on.  Unless you *want* to avoid unused positions in your count array, then maybe you want `c - 'A'` as your array index.  But probably not if you have one array for all characters and digits you want to count.

#### Example

For the loop structure, I have out-of-range characters jump over the `Do Something` part, reaching the compare/branch loop condition.  The load and index increment happens every iteration, regardless of the loaded character.

Note that every character that's not in any of the ranges is a non-digit *and* a non-letter.  It doesn't make sense to have a non-digit branch target separate from a non-letter branch target because that's not what you're figuring out.  You could have digit and letter branch to separate places, though.

```
_asm
{
   xor  esi, esi   ; i=0

Loop1:                           ; do {
   ; load from the array *inside* the loop.
   movzx ebx, byte ptr LocalBuffer[esi]
   inc   esi                          ; ebp = buf[i++]

 ; check for digits first
   lea   eax, [ebx - '0']
   cmp   al, 9
   jbe   CharCount                    ; if (c-'0' <= 9) goto CharCount
 ; non-digits fall through into checking for alphabetic

   mov   eax, ebx
   or    eax, 20h       ; force to lower-case
   sub   eax, 'a'       ; subtract start of the range
   cmp   al, 'z'-'a'    ; see if it was inside the length of the range (unsigned)
   ja    skipCount
; in the common case (alphabetic characters), fall through into CharCount

CharCount:
; EBX still holds the character value, zero-extended
   add  byte ptr [counts + ebx], 1       ;Do something
    ; or use  [counts + ebx*4] if you have an int array.

skipCount:    ; rejected characters jump here, skipping count increment
   cmp  esi, 127
   jb   Loop1               ; } while(i<127)
}
```

You don't need to waste a 2nd register on another loop counter (ECX) when you already have ESI.  `cmp/jb` is more efficient than the `loop` instruction anyway.

I think we can save one instruction by doing the subtract first (so we can still use `lea` to copy-and-subtract), but then we have to *clear* the 0x20 bit instead of setting it so we're dealing with upper-case.

```
;; untested, but I think this is correct, too, using LEA+AND instead of MOV+OR+SUB
   lea   eax, [ebx - 'A']
   and   eax, ~20h        ; clear the lower-case bit
   cmp   al, 'Z'-'A'      ; 25, same as 'z'-'a' of course.
   ja    skipCount
```

`c - 'A'` = 0x20 for `c='a'`.  Character codes past `'Z'` but before `'a'` produce smaller results so clearing the `0x20` bit can't give us a false-positive.

---

PS: if this is the same histogram problem you asked previous questions about, you don't need to filter while reading, just make your array of counts have 256 elements (for every possible `uint8_t` value) and then only loop over the ones you want to print.

If you were getting segfaults using `ebx` as the index, that's because you loaded 4 bytes (a large integer) instead of zero-extending one.  We already fixed this bug in previous versions of you question.

Also, as I previously [explained in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58782181/why-am-i-getting-this-weird-looking-output#comment103849249_58782181), you don't need to copy your string input to a `LocalBuffer`, just do `char *bufptr = Buffer;` and in inline asm do `mov esi, bufptr` to get that pointer into a register.  That's inefficient, but much better than copying a whole array.  Especially for counts as well.

Or https://godbolt.org/z/QszVMf shows how to access class members from inline asm.